# Should i write migrations every time i want to create table in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations, laravel-models

So basicly i have started working with laravel. And to this moment i have been writing migrations and defining the fields there. And after that i should create a model related to it and define the relationships there. Unlike the Django framework where you define fields and relationships inside a model and migrations created automaticly.

Thus my question is:
Is there any other way of writing the migrations so that i don't need to write models as well. Or am i stuck with writing everything myself?

I have tried:
php artisan make:model User -m
in console, but it only creates the file and that's it

Would appreciate the sources if there are any

Comment: same way you use `php artisan make:model` you can do `php artisan make:migration`, the `-m` does the same thing

Comment: You can always use https://drawsql.app/ to generate the Laravel model and migration file.

Comment: You can check this discussion https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/6927.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should write a migration for each table / model you wish to create.

If you create the migration, the model will automatically have all the correct fields as attributes.